# Which of the following grids does not fit into the pattern?

Tags: pattern, visual

[image]

The grids in the set above are not put in order, but there is a pattern.

Answer (score 3):

My answer:

> The one on the **right**.
>
>  All the other diagrams have their blocks connected (horizontally, vertically or diagonally). This one has an isolated block.

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: Well, it could be anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is:

> **The 5th count from left**, due to there are only 1 or 2 separated white connected grid groups in each image but not the 5th which has 6 white connected grid groups.

Answer (score 0):

I think:

> **The 5th from the left.**

Because:

> It is the only one that doesn't have a sibling block with +1 or -1 black squares.
>
>  Block 2 has one more black square than block 1
>  Block 3 has one more black square than block 2
>  Block 4 has one more black square than block 3
>  Block 7 has one more black square than block 6

Comment: rot13(Oybpx 6 nyfb unf 2 zber oynpx fdhnerf guna oybpx 5, fb gung zvtug nf jryy or gur fbyhgvba)

Comment: whats this mean?